# Tensorflow not linking operations into single CUDA kernel

Tags: tensorflow

I've just started learning how to use Tensorflow and have run into an issue that's making me doubt my understanding of how it should work. I want to get a rough idea of how much performance I should be getting using basic arithmetical operations on a GPU. I create a one dimensional tensor of 100 million elements and then chain 1000 add operations on this tensor. My expectation is that the Tensorflow run-time would be able to link these operations into a single CUDA kernel that's executed on the GPU, however when I run it it seems that each operation is being issued to the GPU separately. It takes around 5 seconds to complete on my gtx 1080 ti, which gives around 20 Gflops. While running, python.exe is using up a full CPU core and Nvidia Nsight shows many kernels being submitted. In comparison, when I try and see what I get with Alea.GPU I get around 3Tflops and a single CUDA kernel issued.

Am I misunderstanding how basic operations should work on a GPU? is the only way to get good GPU efficiency to manually group operations into more complex custom operations or use the higher level ML functions?

Thank you.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

TENSOR_SIZE=100000000
TF_REP=1000

def testSpeed(x):
    tf.InteractiveSession();

    z=tf.zeros(TENSOR_SIZE)

    for i in range(0, TF_REP):
        z=tf.add(z,x)

    return tf.reduce_sum(z).eval();

x=tf.range(0.0, TENSOR_SIZE)


t0=time.perf_counter()  
testSpeed(x)
t1=time.perf_counter()

print("Time taken "+str(t1-t0)+"s gflops= " + str(TENSOR_SIZE * TF_REP / 1000000000.0 / (t1 - t0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should separate your code into 2 stages, a `build_graph` stage, which defines the various tensors. I suggest collecting them in a function called `build_graph()`. Then create your session and run data through it. You are trying to apply procedural programming techniques to an imperative library.

Next is the issue of swapping data onto and off of the GPU. When you run `tf.reduce_sum(z).eval()` you are copying the result from GPU back to CPU every time.

Lastly, you are creating many sessions with `tf.InteractiveSession()`, you should only have 1 session created. Go back to the first issue to resolve this. A best practice is to never create tensorflow OPs after the session has been created. Tensorflow will allow you to, but as a best practice don't, and you shouldn't need to if you coded things correctly. If you feel like you need to, post a question asking why you can't do XYZ without defining it before the session was created and someone will almost certainly offer a correction to the workflow.